# Inconsistent contextual color naming for B.S. color classes

Tags: bootstrap-4

The bootstrap colors defined [B.S. Background Colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/#background-color) for background are different (or maybe of different intensity!) from those that are defined [B.S.Contextual Class Colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/#contextual-classes) for the list group.
My question is: What is the reason for this seemingly inconsistent naming? (Please explain if I am wrong). Thanks.

Comment: What is the inconsistency you're referring to? That one is dark blue and the other is light?

Comment: @SergChernata, if they have the same name, why is the intensity different? Is there a way to reduce/increase the intensity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These two are actually quite different.

List item is background and text color predefined in one class - `list-group-item list-group-item-primary`. The colors in question are defined within the second class. This is an actual opinion on styling embedded within the framework.

The second example however is constructed with various classes that specifically declare the background and text colors - `bg-primary text-white`. I would argue that this example is more "random" than `list-group-item-primary`. They're merely showing you some ways you could combine the classes. This is less opinionated than the list.

I would also say that the list styling is more friendly to the idea of having multiple colored items in one list. If they were at full opacity the end result would be overwhelming. Saturated, full opacity backgrounds are a little better for "one-off" element highlights.

Last but not least, the source color is actually the same. If you lower the opacity of `bg-primary`, it looks exactly like the muted version around `0.3` value.

Answer (score 1):

The **background colors** *utility* classes are strictly for background color with the no "opinion" on the foreground/text color. This is why the `text-white` utility class is also used to set the text color in the doc examples.

The **contextual colors** are "[stateful background and color](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/list-group/#contextual-classes)" so both the background color *and* contrasting text color is defined. These colors are also used on tables and alerts.

---

Bootstrap uses SASS functions to create contextual colors from the [theme colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/theming/#theme-colors). The `$theme-color-level` function uses the `$theme-color-interval` var which you can change as desired and then regenerate the list-group-item variants...

```
@each $color, $value in $theme-colors {
      @include list-group-item-variant($color, theme-color-level($color, -3), theme-color-level($color, 3));
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/SfpaYAjsUM

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Both answers given deserve to be marked as the answer, but I only had 1 to choose!